# Firebase intenal error when testing authentication desktop_app

Tags: c++, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have tried running "testapp_desktop" for authentication using Firebase C++ SDK, cloned from github:

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-cpp/

I have set the path to Firebase SDK C++ and the project is built successfully and the services for anonymous and email/password are enabled on Firebase dashboard. The problem is that none of the authentication tests are passed by showing "An internal error has occurred". The complete log for the tests is shown below:

```
Starting Auth tests.
Firebase App initializing app __FIRAPP_DEFAULT (default 1).
Created the Firebase app 16d09c0.
Created the Auth 16d33a0 class for the Firebase app.
No user signed in at creation time.
AuthStateListener called 0 times on registration.
IdTokenListener called 0 times on registration.
AuthStateListener called 0 times on SignOut() when already signed-out.
IdTokenListener called 0 times on SignOut() when already signed-out.
  Calling Auth::SignInAnonymously()...
ERROR: Auth::SignInAnonymously() completed with error: 1, `An internal error has occurred.`
ERROR: AuthStateListener called 0 times on SignInAnonymously().
ERROR: IdTokenListener called 0 times on SignInAnonymously().
Current user (nil)
ERROR: AuthStateListener called 0 times on SignOut().
ERROR: IdTokenListener called 0 times on SignOut().
Current user (nil)
  Calling CreateUserWithEmailAndPassword() to create temp user...
ERROR: CreateUserWithEmailAndPassword() to create temp user completed with error: 1, `An internal error has occurred.`
ERROR: Could not register new user.
  Calling Auth::SignInAnonymously() for User...
ERROR: Auth::SignInAnonymously() for User completed with error: 1, `An internal error has occurred.`
  Calling Auth::CreateUserWithEmailAndPassword() new email for delete...
ERROR: Auth::CreateUserWithEmailAndPassword() new email for delete completed with error: 1, `An internal error has occurred.`
  Calling Auth::SignInAnonymously() at end...
ERROR: Auth::SignInAnonymously() at end completed with error: 1, `An internal error has occurred.`
Completed Auth tests.
```

Any help is highly appreciated,

Comment: If you want to report a bug with the sample, please report a bug on the repo. If you want us to help with a code problem, post the [minimal, complete code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question itself.

Comment: If you clone: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-cpp/ as I wrote, so there is a sample code for authentication. All you need is a valid google-services.json file that is generated by Firebase and is actually irrelevant to this question. I don't really get what you need more than the repo itself.